# Stop loading Webview in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, webview

I have react native project on Android platform.
I have a Webview loaded from url. When user click any url, i want navigate to screen in my app and webview will stop loading. So in my onNavigationStateChange() function

```
  source = {{uri:this.props.htmlUrl}}
    ref='_webView'
    scrollEnabled={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    onNavigationStateChange ={(navState)=>{
      //handle navigate another screen
       this.refs._webView.stopLoading();
    }}
```

It works. So when i go back, and click other url, I can not touch any url in webview.
If someone meet the same issue, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to stop loading the webview, it will stop loading when it's finished loading the web page you're on.  Also, onNavigationStateChange isn't the best place to stop a WebView, log the navState, you'll see it gets called many times before the page has fully finished loading.  You don't want to stop loading the page before most of the items on it have fully loaded.  

If you're trying to stop a running script on the page, you should look at injecting JavaScript into the WebView to stop the script from continuing.

Comment: https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/communicating-between-react-native-and-the-webview-ac14b8b8b91a

Answer (score 2):

Use `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` prop of `react-native-webview` package.

`onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={event => {if(event.url==="XXXX") return false; return true;}}`

p.s. Return true from the function to continue loading the request and false to stop loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate url to enter and when click back navigator, you enter to link only have validation.

```
source = {{uri:this.props.htmlUrl}}
    ref='_webView'
    scrollEnabled={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    onNavigationStateChange ={(navState)=>{
       if(navState.url == ""){ // You must validate url to enter or navigate
          this.refs._webView.stopLoading();
       }
    }}
```